# Filter Object data by searching in input | Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

Filter the contents inside an array using input without using Pipe.

**Array**

```
{
    "passengerId":"integer",
    "survived":"integer",
    "Pclass":"integer",
    "Name":"string",
    "Sex":"string",
    "Ticket":"string"
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="column-wrapper">
  <input type="text" placeholder="search" (keyup)="search($event)">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let columnName of columnData">
      <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" [(ngModel)]="columnName.visible" [checked]="columnName">
      <p>{{columnName}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
search($event:any){
  this.searchTerm = $event.target.value;
  this.filtered = this.columnData.filter((data:any) => data === this.searchTerm);
}
```

**OutPut**

On entering text inside input,

for eg : "**passenger**"
Result : `passenger`.

[image]

Comment: Your data as indicated in the question does not seem to be an array, an array is denoted with square brackets `[]` and is index (0,1,2,3....) based and not `key:value` pairs. It will really help if you create a demo (on stackblitz) of your setup and what you have tried, people will be able to help you better.

Comment: It seems like you are comparing an object with a string, so the filtering won't be accurate.